# A way of copying a plot and plotting next to existing curve

Tags: matlab

If I have a curve plotted in an axis is there a way of copying the curve and plotting next to it without running the function.

I.e. I have a code to plot a function from -1 to 0, I dont want the function to be correct from 0 to 1, I simply want to replicate the curve next to it.

Sorry for vague question but Im at a loss here

Answer (score 3):

Using the function `sin(x)` as an example, you could do this

```
x_min = -1;
x_max = 0;
x = x_min:0.1:x_max;
y = sin(x);

hold on
plot(x, y, 'LineWidth', 1.2)
plot(x + x_max - x_min, y, 'LineWidth', 1.2)
plot([x_max x_max], [sin(x_min) sin(x_max)], 'k--')
axis equal
```

to get the following

[image]

Comment: If the function didn't work for say 0.3, would this work though? The function I am plotting only works from -1 to 0, but I need to replicate the image simply for illustrative reasons

Comment: @user3541401 It should work. The values of the function are shifted to the right without evaluating the function on [0, 1].